# how to identify columns from 2 identical tables that doesn't have the same value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a system that moderates applicants, so first the admin needs to validate all of the applicants information before they can be list as accepted applicants, but the problem is every time the user modify any of his/her information, the user must reapply his/her application, so the admin will need to re-validate the applicants info,but i want to highlight those modified fields so the admin doesnt need to review all the information.
After spending some time on google, i came up to this idea,I created a trigger that insert the the record from table 1 before the modifications,to table 2. So now i want to select only the columns, that has been updated by the user but i don't know and i can't find something that does the said function.

Comment: You could also have the trigger examine the old and new records, making note of which columns have changed.

Comment: Alain Collins, sir how can i do that?

Comment: In your trigger context you have OLD.column and NEW.column values for your table's columns available.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have a primary key.  In this example, I used 'email' and only check for changes in two columns:

```
SELECT *
from table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 on t1.email = t2.email
WHERE (t1.fname != t2.fname)
OR (t1.lname != t2.lname)
```

Comment: I want to select the column that has been modified, not the data. but thanks anyways